# Hacer que aparezca un elemento dado un evento en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, interfaz-gráfica, javascript-objeto

Estoy intentando hacer una página de LogIn muy sencilla con ReactJS y me gustaría que cuando se deje un apartado en blanco, salte un texto en rojo diciendo que tienes que rellenar ese apartado.

De momento tengo esto:

```
function LogIn(props) {

    const [user, setUser] = React.useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");

    const classes = useStyles();

    const keyPress = (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            if (user === '' || user === null || user === undefined) {
                alert("user mandatory field");
                Credentials_Text();
            } else if (password === '' || password === null || password === undefined) {
                alert("password mandatory field")
            } else {
                console.log('user', user);
                console.log('password', password);
                alert("Your data is being uploaded!: \nUser:  " + user + "\nPassword:  " + password)
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="LogIn">
            <header className="LogIn-header">
                <img src={freezeZX} className="zx" alt="logo"/>
                <div className="container">
                    <img src={logIn} className="LogIn-logo" alt="logo"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className={classes.margin}>
                        <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="flex-end">
                            <Grid item>
                                <AccountCircle/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <TextField id="input-with-icon-grid" label="User"
                                           InputProps={{className: classes.input}}
                                           onChange={handleUserChange}/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </div>
                    <div className={classes.margin}>
                        <Grid container spacing={1} alignItems="flex-end">
                            <Grid item>
                                <VpnKeyIcon/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item>
                                <TextField id="input-with-icon-grid" label="Password" type="password"
                                           InputProps={{className: classes.input}}
                                           onKeyDown={keyPress}
                                           onChange={handlePasswordChange}/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Me gustaría que cuando el usuario entrase en esta parte del código (la que revisa si todo está completo) poder hacer aparecer el elemento de texto.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías agregar otra variable de estado

```
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
```

En tu evento keyPress, en reemplazar los alerts por:

```
const keyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        if (user === '' || user === null || user === undefined) {
            setError({ name: 'user', msg: 'user mandatory field' })
            Credentials_Text();
        } else if (password === '' || password === null || password === undefined) {
            setError({ name: 'password', msg: 'user mandatory field' })
        } else {
            console.log('user', user);
            console.log('password', password);
            setError(null);
            alert("Your data is being uploaded!: \nUser:  " + user + "\nPassword:  " + password)
        }
    }
}
```

Finalmente, en algún lugar de tu render colocar algo como:

```
{error && <span>{error.msg}</span>}
```

También podrías hacer una validación similar, pero en un evento `onBlur` de tus campos de texto.

Comment: Es justo lo que acabé haciendo. Añadir un estado, pero me pregunto si no hay forma de añadir otros elementos en caso de que suceda un evento

Comment: Añadir otros elementos es posible haciendo algo similar. Los elementos podrían llegar por props o debes definirlos tu dentro del componente. La mayoria de los casos se evita añadir añadir elementos HTML como tal (ej. con appendChild()) a menos que quieras controlarlos directamente, como sucederia con un grafico.